# Flutter Map Heatmap - IOS/Android creating shaded tiles

Tags: flutter, dart, maps, heatmap

I am attempting to use the flutter_map_heatmap library. I am having what seems to be a tile rendering issue on IoS and Android but it works perfectly fine on web. Instead of showing a coloured heatmap it gives me tiles of shadows. I have a layer selection widget that uses toggles to turn layers on and off which works fine. I have a few other layers in this widget which work on all platforms, its just this heatmap...

I have a feeling that the tile is loaded differently on a mobile device but this is not really my domain.

Map layers state

```
List<Widget> mapLayers = [];
```

Sets the TileLayer for the map and the current location marker on init

```
@override
void initState() {
  reverseGeo().then(
    (location) => {
      setState(
        () {
          LatLng loc = LatLng(location.latitude!, location.longitude!);
          mapCenter = loc;
          mapLayers = [
            TileLayer(
              key: const Key("tile_layer"),
              urlTemplate:'https://atlas.microsoft.com/map/tile/png?subscription-key=${AppConfig.mapsApiKey}&api-version=1.0&layer=basic&style=main&zoom={z}&x={x}&y={y}',
              tileProvider: CancellableNetworkTileProvider(),
            ),
            currentLocationMarker(loc)
          ];
          isMapLoading = false;
        },
      )
    },
  );
  super.initState();
}
```

Function to add and remove the heatmap layer when toggled

```
void _manageLayer(String layer, bool toggled) {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
        _rebuildStream.add(null);
    });
    if (toggled) {
      MyHeatmap.build(context).then(
        (value) => {
          setState(() {
            _addLayer(
              HeatMapLayer(
                key: Key(AppConfig.heatmap),
                  heatMapDataSource: InMemoryHeatMapDataSource(data: value),
                  heatMapOptions: HeatMapOptions(
                    radius: 50,
                    gradient: gradients[index],
                    minOpacity: 0.4,
                  ),
                  reset: _rebuildStream.stream,
                ),
             );
         }),
       },
     );
   } else {
      _removeLayer(AppConfig.heatmap);
   }
}

void _addLayer(layer) {
    setState(() {
        // Inserts layer at last index to keep location marker on top
        mapLayers.insert(mapLayers.length - 1, layer);
   });
}

void _removeLayer(String key) {
  setState(() {
    mapLayers = mapLayers
      .where((element) => element.key.toString() != "[<'$key'>]")
      .toList();
  });
}
```

This is what it looks like on mobile

[image: Android and IO]

This is what it looks like on web

[image: Web Output]